# Easiest two-way encryption to be used both on a PHP server and on iOS client

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, encryption

**For private use only**, I'm creating and hosting on my web server a PHP application that retrieves all my passwords for various accounts from a MySQL database and serves them to the client that is an iPhone application which should also be able to insert new passwords in the database.

Instead of sending this data over the internet as plain text I would like to encrypt them before sending them but I'm very new to encryption so I'm feeling a little bit disoriented among all the possible encryption algorithms out there.

While the `mcrypt` function on PHP seems to be very flexible and compatible with many encryption algorithms I couldn't find anything like that on iOS.

What I wanted was some algorithm easy to implement both on PHP and Objective-C that, given some plain text and an encryption key (stored both on the server and on the client), would encrypt AND decrypt the plain text.

For further detail the server/client communication I had in mind was something like this:

1. Client sends a request containing some client-specific-app-ID and the service
   whose password the server should return
2. The server checks if that client ID is allowed to get that information
3. If the client is allowed then the server querys the database and
   retrieves the password
4. The server encrypts the password and sends it to the client
5. The client decrypts the password and shows it to the user

This thing is for personal use only so I don't need unbreakable security because probably nobody will care breaking it.
I'm doing this just for research and to get started with encryption. I know this is not secure at all.

Do you guys know any two-way encryption algorithm that is easy to use both on php and objective-c that I can use to encrypt passwords on the server and decrypt them in iOS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't bother with your own encryption. You just need to use an SSL link, e.g.

```
https://yourserver.example.com/getpasswords.php
    ^---
```

SSL gives you the encryption for free, and as a bonus allows the iOS client to be reasonably sure that it's connecting to YOUR server, and not some malicious fake server.

Comment: Do you know any good tutorial to get started with SSL? As I said I'm very new to encryption and I'm very confused.

Comment: The 'hard' part of SSL is configuring the server. Once you've got that settled, you just start using `https` instead of `http` urls.

Comment: So it is just something that regards apache, no php involved. Is that right?

Comment: generally speaking, nothing in PHP would change at all. it just sees an http request come in, and responds to it. apache will take care of all the ssl business.

Comment: ok I'll search how to configure SSL on my web server then! Thank you sir!

Comment: I set up ssl on the server and got everything working fine but there is something that I need to ask you. In order to make this as more scure possible should I bundle a copy of the certificate in the app and compare it with the certificate provided by the server to the client?

Comment: no. you need to keep the cert private, otherwise anyone could impersonate your server. the client will validate the cert by checking if it's been signed by a recognized CA. e.g. you don't need to import an Amazon certificate to be able to use ssl on amazon.com. you just need to have amazon's root CA in your browser, which happens to be Verisign.